# Table missing from database in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an sqlite database stored in `assets/databases/minitest.db` and I try to copy it to the local filesystem from the assets folder and then open it.

When I open it I get a table not found exception.

I am pretty sure it's not something wrong with the database itself because when I open it with an sqlite viewer it looks just fine. I've been googling this problem for about 2 hours now and I have seen a bunch of similar questions but none of their solutions seem to work so I really don't know what to do.

Code:

```
mydatabase = new DataBaseHelper(c).myDataBase;
Cursor mCursor = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT third FROM Trigrams WHERE first='" + first.toLowerCase() + "' AND second ='" + second.toLowerCase() + "' ORDER BY freq DESC LIMIT 0,3", null);
```

Complete DataBaseHelper:

```
class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context mycontext;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "minitest.db";    
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/" +       BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/databases/";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 3;
    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.mycontext = context;
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if (dbexist) {
            System.out.println("Database exists");
            opendatabase();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
            createdatabase();
            opendatabase();
        }
    }

    public void createdatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if (dbexist) {
            System.out.println(" Database exists.");
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copydatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkdatabase() {

        boolean checkdb = false;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        }
        return checkdb;
    }

    private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open("databases/" + DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

        // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();
    }

    public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null) {
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            try {
                copydatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Trigrams
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Trigrams (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT third FROM Trigrams WHERE first='a' AND second ='baby' ORDER BY freq DESC LIMIT 0,3
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1355)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1294)
    at com.chair49.sentimentkeyboard.analysis.NextWord.getNextWords(NextWord.java:38)
    at com.chair49.sentimentkeyboard.SimpleIME.onKey(SimpleIME.java:125)
    at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.detectAndSendKey(KeyboardView.java:828)
    at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.repeatKey(KeyboardView.java:1371)
    at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onModifiedTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1281)
    at android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.onTouchEvent(KeyboardView.java:1214)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9337)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2198)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2198)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2198)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2198)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2554)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2198)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2432)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1746)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:787)
    at android.inputmethodservice.SoftInputWindow.dispatchTouchEvent(SoftInputWindow.java:93)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2393)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9557)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4263)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4102)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3644)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3697)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3663)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3789)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3671)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3846)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3644)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3697)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3663)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3671)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3644)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5955)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5929)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5890)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6058)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(Inp
07-14 14:12:42.161 14083-14083/com.chair49.sentimentkeyboard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: What happens if you try to open the `.db` file using Android's `sqlite3` command line?

Comment: I might be wrong.. But I believe that onUpgrade is failing. You call: opendatabase() which opens database. This, will cause onUpgrade() and it will try to copy from asset folder. However, since your database is opened, you can not write and this way, your app is keeping the old database.

Comment: Is there a table called Trigrams?, is the spelling correct?

Comment: It works if you unistall/reinstall the app?

Comment: wow I feel dumb, it works after uninstalling and reinstalling. Sorry guys, should have tried that. I just wasted 3 hours of my life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your database is not being updated. I faced similar issue dealing with database in `asset` folder.

**Workflow during onUpdate**:

When you update your database (it already exists), following methods would be invoked:

```
opendatabase()->SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()
```

This will open your database and also, will trigger `onUpgrade()`.

In your `onUpgrade()`, you try:

```
onUpgrade()->copydatabase()
```

However, database is opened you will not be able to overwrite file `minitest.db`

This will cause a `IOException` and database is not updated.

You did not see that exception because you are handling `IOException`.

**How to Confirm**

You can uninstall/install (or just delete data) your app. If works fine, it seems that database is corrected but during some update, it failed your your tables were not updated.

You can also update database number to 4 and check the log messages and confirm that `onUpgrade()` is failing.

**Workaround**

This is how I do:

```
class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private boolean shouldBeUpdated;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
        ...
        shouldBeUpdated = false;

        if (dbexist) {
            System.out.println("Database exists");
            opendatabase();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
            createdatabase();
            opendatabase();
        }
    }

    public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        // CLOSE DATABASE BEFORE UPDATING IT
        close();

        if(shouldBeUpdated) {
            try {
                copydatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            shouldBeUpdated = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you :)